# assigning empty list to StringListProperty with default value results in entity having default value?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Fully working example below can be run in the interactive console.

Is this expected? If so, I have two questions:

1) please show where this is explained in the GAE documentation.

2) please show a pattern for a `db.Model` that defaults to a populated list for some property at the moment of creation, but still allows us to assign the empty list (or None) at a later moment.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class TestClass(db.Model):
    my_string_list = db.StringListProperty(default=['foo', 'bar'])

instance = TestClass()
instance.put()

print instance.my_string_list
#['foo', 'bar']

instance.my_string_list = []
instance.put()
print instance.my_string_list
#[]

instance2 = db.get(instance.key())
print instance2.my_string_list
#expected [], got ['foo', 'bar'] ???
```

Comment: That is odd, poking around it looks like its stored in the datastore as an empty list, but when its read back out, it's default value is placed back. Maybe an error withe GAE? I'd open an issue on the issue tracker

Comment: done: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9098&thanks=9098&ts=1364912386

Comment: While this is odd, it's generally bad idea to pass mutable objects as default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that with NDB (the newer datastore API), repeated, required and default are mutally exclusive. That is, there can't be default values for repeated properties (such as StringListProperty). Maybe you need a redesign, instead of using default value, make a function for getting a new instance of your model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class TestClass(db.Model):
    my_string_list = db.StringListProperty(default=[])

    @classmethod
    def get_new_instance(cls):
       entity = cls()
       entity.my_string_list = ['foo', 'bar']
       return entity
```

This is all assuming the bug report you opened won't be addressed for a while. If they don't support this on NDB, it may turn into a similar situation with the old DB API.